# What batter was used on Birds Eye potato fritters?

Tags: batter, restaurant-mimicry

Birds eye sadly no longer make these, a very common potato side in the 70s and 80s which I'm trying to recreate. The batter was very light and golden, almost like a tempura batter, sort of flaky but crispy at the same time. The potato was quite dense, if memory serves correctly, it was whole potato pre-cooked, rather than a croquette like mixture.

I've tried using a seasoned plain flour and water batter (using both plain and self-raising flour with sparkling water), but the consistency was too doughy.

I suspect they have added some ingredient to the batter in the same way professional bakers add flour improver to bread.

Any suggestions as to what I could try? I was thinking of a very thin tempura batter with smoked paprika to give colouring using par-boiled potato discs, but I'm not sure if this would adhere properly or be the correct thickness. The batter on the fritters was a few millimetres thick, but nowhere near as thick as you would get on fried fish for instance.

Comment: Did you try adding baking powder?

Comment: Were they "Birds Eye Oven Bake Potato Fritters"? In which case, Spar have a [page listing the ingredients](https://www.spar.co.uk/deals-and-groceries/frozen-foods/frozen-potato-products/other-frozen-potato-products/birds-eye-oven-bake-potato-fritters-650g) with "Batter (Wheat Flour, Skimmed Milk Powder, Salt, Baking Powder (contains Rasing Agents E450, E500))". Sunflower oil is used.

Comment: Packet looks different from what I remember, but the BP and SMP sound like the key ingredients to me. What sort of ratio would I need of these?

Comment: Andrew: that sounds like an answer, post it?

Comment: ["Coodjegoa burdzeye potato frittur?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4T6BzPudRLs) - ah, the memories of my Scottish childhood.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I didn't get notified of your comment and only saw it just now when I was looking at my "All actions" section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spar used to have a page* for "Birds Eye Oven Bake Potato Fritters" listing the ingredients with "Batter (Wheat Flour, Skimmed Milk Powder, Salt, Baking Powder (contains Rasing Agents E450, E500))". Sunflower oil is used.

* Lost, and not even available through the Wayback Machine as far as I can find: https://www.spar.co.uk/deals-and-groceries/frozen-foods/frozen-potato-products/other-frozen-potato-products/birds-eye-oven-bake-potato-fritters-650g